# Alternative to iOS 10 Music app which is now missing star rating

Tags: itunes, ios

I'm using the phone to categorise my ripped music while I'm on the train or whatever. I sync this with iTunes to have the same information available on my Mac. With iOS 10 I am no longer able to do so, because Apple seems to think like/dis-like is enough choice.

I don't concur with this view.

What iOS Apps are you using on your Mac and iPhone to categorise music ? I'm even open to leave the iTunes universe all-together.

The star system is cumbersome, but still quite ok to classify songs in a simple way:

1 - defect , 2 - like, 3 - party song, 4 - mixtape song, 5 - reserved

This is definitely more information that love and hate.

So what's your take on listening and categorising to **your** mp3 files on your iOS device and Mac ?

Comment: Flagging for closure as [off-topic](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) because all answers will be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I beg to differ. This is not about what editor as better than the other. This is about a feature that was taken away by apple and biting people around the world. People are using notepads again to remember their star rating when they are on the train. So... Yeah.. This may be opinionated but there is no easy solution, because apple changed the rules.

Comment: You end your post with "what's your take," which is literally an English idiom for "what's your opinion". The only other sentence in your post with a question mark is asking for app recommendations, which are also generally off-topic. Your post neatly defines bullet points 1 and 3 on the "avoid asking" list that @fbara linked (and 5, to a degree).

Answer (score 1):

Cesium Music Player includes your iTunes metadata and allows you to change star ratings while listening to music on your iPhone

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cesium-music-player/id924491991?mt=8